# Google maps don't work in fieldset with jQuery Slide Up/Down

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, google-maps, fieldset

For my submit form I used fieldsets they will slide up and slide down with jQuery if the previous fieldset is valid.
At fieldset number 3 there will be a map of google maps to locate the address of the customer based on longitude and latitude.

```
<fieldset id="werkgebied" style="display: none;">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="adres">Uw Adres</label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6" id="stapwerkgebied_adres">

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                 </div>
                                                 <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="form-group">

                                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="adres">Werkgebied</label>
                                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                                            <div id="kaartje" style="width:400px;height:400px;"></div> 

                                                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                                            var map;
                                                            var centerpoint;

                                                            function initmap(latvar=52.3747388,longvar=4.7585307){
                                                                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('kaartje'), {
                                                              center: {lat: Number(latvar), lng: Number(longvar)},
                                                              zoom: 9
                                                            });
                                                            var kmRadius = $("#aantalkm").val();
                                                            circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                                                                center: {lat: Number(latvar), lng: Number(longvar)},
                                                                map: map,
                                                                strokeColor: '#000',
                                                                strokeWeight: 2,
                                                                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                                                                fillColor: '#046e94',
                                                                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                                                                radius: kmRadius * 1000
                                                            });
                                                            }
                                                            function updateMarker(coord) {
                                                                var kmRadius = $("#aantalkm").val();
                                                                circle.setRadius(kmRadius*1000);
                                                            }
                                                            </script>
                                                            <script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDnsp8B8c942fe8i42UEAImAcAoTbDVYN4&callback=initmap">
</script>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="aantalkm">Afstand (km)</label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-2"><input id="aantalkm" class="form-control" type="text" onChange="updateMarker()" value="20" />
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                     </div>
                                                     <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="submit"></label>
                                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                    <button type="button" id="werkgebied_prev" class="btn btn-primary mb-xl previous">Vorige</button>
                                                                    <button type="button" id="werkgebied_next" class="btn btn-primary mb-xl next">Verder</button>
                                                                </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                     </div>
                                                </fieldset>
```

When fieldset 3 shows up the map will not work. If I delete the:

```
style="display: none;"
```

The map will work but isn't hide till the previous 2 fieldsets a valide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the `display:none` style set on the `fieldset`. Google map needs the target element to be visible for the correct initialization. In your situation you can do a little trick, and create the element for the google map on the fly, move it using css out of the viewport, wait until the map is fully initialized (for that you can use the `tilesloaded` event) and after than move the map node to your `fieldset`. Here is a little fiddle which can help you https://jsfiddle.net/9a2nwe2b/1/.

You can see that the `fieldset` is hidden, and after displaying it the map is fully working.